# iPhone and Android - Appcelerator Titanium complex view with labels stacking

Tags: titanium

We need to design a page like this with a tap on the blue username redirecting to the users page. How is this possible in Ti. The data is dynamic from the webservices and the text may increase also..

Any help is appreciated

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBzBx.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're first try should be to set the `label.height='auto'`. the second way would be to calculate the height

```
var charsPerLine = 20; //depends on font-properties
var tmp = Math.round(text.length/charsPerLine);
label.height = tmp;
```

hope it helps a little bit

Answer (score 0):

cannot be done without a lot of crazy calculations to determine the length of the name field.

i would suggest change the UI if you want to use appcelerator

Comment: Is that possible with iPhone XCode development. as i have seen lot of apps (instagram) doing this neatly.. Would you suggest me doing calculations and then show it :( . I am not a fan of doing crazy unwanted calculations :(